# Strange caching

Tags: php, html, perl, content-management-system, movabletype

So, I have been asked to remove a menu item on a website running `Movable Type`.

So I log in, and try to figure out WHERE those templates can be edited. I finally find something that looks real, edit it, update the page and NOTHING HAPPENED.

I then log in to the FTP and discover that ALL pages `example.com/about/whatever.html` are stored as plain HTML pages in exactly the places where the path tells (whatever.html is stored in /about/ etc)

Is there some kind of hard-cache going on, that I can disable, or flush somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you need to republish files [the circular icon next to the Tools menu].

MT does allow for template module caching, but if you're editing templates via the MT user interface, then it's not likely this is the problem. Just republish, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read [most of the docs](http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/).

MT generates static files at the time they are published to avoid the run time overhead of generating documents from scratch for each request.

If you have made changes outside of MT to templates, you should regenerate the static files from MT's control panel.